# Tab out of asp.net auto complete textbox after user selects an item (using enter or mouse click)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, autocompletebox

I am using asp.net auto complete textbox and everything is working fine. I just need to tab out of that textbox after user selects an item (either by using enter or mouse click on one of the items)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('input').autocomplete({
autoFocus: true,
source: ["test","some text"],
delay: 0,
select: function(event, ui) { if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
   $(this).next("input").focus().select();
} }
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/YbPVX/5/

Comment: I am using asp auto complete textbox; not the jquery one. :(